# How to enable behavioral marketing with cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have done some research, looking for the right answer, but nothing was specific.  First of all, I saw sites on how to create a cookie, but it was not clear how it would be useful for me.

Recently, I was buying a gift for someone and went to a clothing store online.  I purchased some items, no when I go to Facebook, for example, I see that clothing stores ads.  I assume there was a cookie put on my computer, in my temp folder, and then Facebook knows to show that ad.

I want to do something similar, but with Google Adwords.  When people go to my website, I want to add a cookie to the user's computer so that when they see Google ads, either through the Display Network or in the Search Network, my Google Ad will come up because they had already shown an interest in my product/service by coming to my site.

This is obviously possible with Facebook ads, but can I do it with Google Ads?  I would like to know how to do this.  Any details or step-by-step resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with remarketing: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453998?hl=en